# How can I make a half "RadialProgressBar"

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-10-universal

I want to make a half "Progressbar" like in the picture.
How can I make. I don't want it to be ready-made.
Platform : UWP

[image]

Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar control in Windows Community Toolkit: [RadialGauge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/radialgauge), you should check that out.
Also, if you want to learn how to make such controls, then refer to the source code of `RadialGauge` [here](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/RadialGauge).

Having said that, you can use `Path` to achieve such UI. This is the result I got:

[image]

from this XAML :

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Path Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="5">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="10,60">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                            <ArcSegment
                                x:Name="DialArc"
                                Point="110,60"
                                Size="50,50"
                                SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Path Stroke="DeepPink" StrokeThickness="5">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="10,60">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                            <ArcSegment
                                Point="60,10"
                                Size="50,50"
                                SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <TextBlock Text="62%" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</Grid>
```

But again, I strongly recommend you use the `RadialGauge` from the Community Toolkit,

Comment: The WinUI library recently picked up a radial progress bar as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answer. I used RadialGauge. This is the result I got:

[image]

```
<Grid>
    <Custom:RadialGauge HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,174,0,0" Value="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Red" MinAngle="-90" MaxAngle="90" Minimum="0" Maximum="180" TickSpacing="0" NeedleWidth="0" Height="591" Width="559" TrailBrush="#FFFF0808" FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="#00000000" ScaleBrush="Black"/>
</Grid>
```

But I could not change the "value" position and I couldn't add units.

Comment: You can add the Unit property of RadialGauge to set the units and if you want to change the "value" position, you can change the Value property to the position you want.

Comment: I couldn't not change the value position but  I made value the transparent. I added new texttblock. I binded the textblock to the value. I add new minRange and maxRange.